# how to get data from api only when users stop typing and/or when users click enter key

Tags: reactjs, api

Below are my 2 js files.

I am passing a method to child which is SearchBox from where I retrieve the value from search text field and call that method inside parent which is CourseList.js. When I get back the value inside parent, I pass that value to fetch api call as query param that retrieves the data from api.

I want to fetch data from api only when users stop typing for 2 seconds and/or when users click enter key. Right now its just getting the data from api on input change so there are multiple calls to api which I do not want.

Here are my code,

CourseList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemAvatar,
  ListItemText,
  Typography,
  Box,
  Divider,
  Grid,
  Button,
  TablePagination,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import LanguageDropdown from "./LanguageDropdown";
import RatingDropdown from "./RatingDropdown";
import CategoryDropdown from "./CategoryDropdown";
import LevelDropdown from "./LevelDropdown";
import StreamDropdown from "./StreamDropdown";

import SearchBox from "./SearchBox";
import CourseSort from "./CourseSort";

import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";

import settings from "../../../../settings";

const getTruncated = (items, value) => {
  // console.log("coming from getTruncated func ", items);

  let cut = items.indexOf(" ", value);
  if (cut == -1) {
    return items;
  }
  return items.substring(0, cut);
};


export default function CourseList(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [myCourses, setMyCourses] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [cate, setCate] = useState(true);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [userLessons, setUserLessons] = useState([]);

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    if (window.location.pathname !== "/portal/ondemand") {
      setCate(false);
    }

    setMyCourses(props.userCourses);
    getInitSignon();

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [search]);

  const getInitSignon = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("cars-crm-token");

    fetch(settings.api().lessons + `?SearchText=${search}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          const error = new Error(res.error);
          throw error;
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("coming from onDemandcourse", data);
        setUserLessons(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  const searchedItem = (value) => {
    setSearch(value)
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Grid container className={classes.searchsort}>
        <Grid item>
          <SearchBox
            className={classes.searchContainer}
            handleSearched={searchedItem}
          />
        </Grid>

      </Grid>

      <Grid className={classes.root}>
        <Grid item className={classes.filters}>
          <Grid direction="column">
            <LanguageDropdown courses={myCourses} />

            {cate && <CategoryDropdown />}

          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item>
          <List className={classes.courses}>
            {userLessons
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((lesson) => (
                <>
                  <div key={lesson.lessonId}>
                    <ListItem
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        alignItems: "flex-start",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        backgroundColor: "#fff",
                        padding: "16px 15px",
                      }}
                    >
                      <ListItemAvatar
                        component={Link}
                        to={`/portal/ondemand/lessons/${lesson.lessonId}`}
                      >
                        <Link
                          to={`/portal/ondemand/lessons/${lesson.lessonId}`}
                        >
                          <img
                            src={lesson.lessonThumbUrl}
                            className={classes.img}
                            alt={lesson.lessonTitle}
                          />
                        </Link>
                      </ListItemAvatar>

                      <ListItemText
                        style={{ margin: "0px" }}
                        primary={
                          <React.Fragment>
                            <Typography
                              component="span"
                              variant="body2"
                              className={classes.inline}
                              color="textPrimary"
                            >
                              <Box fontSize={20}>
                                <Typography
                                  className={classes.courseTitle}
                                  variant="h6"
                                >
                                  {lesson.lessonTitle}
                                </Typography>
                              </Box>
                              <Grid
                                container
                                direction="row"
                                justify="space-between"
                                style={{ margin: "12px 0", maxWidth: "50rem" }}
                              >
                                <Grid item>
                                  <Box fontStyle="italic">
                                    <Typography variant="h6">
                                      Code: {lesson.courseCode} &nbsp; | &nbsp;
                                      {lesson.lessonCreated
                                        ? lesson.lessonCreated.split("T")[0]
                                        : undefined}{" "}
                                      &nbsp; | &nbsp;Course:{" "}
                                      {lesson.courseTitle}
                                    </Typography>
                                  </Box>
                                </Grid>
                              </Grid>
                            </Typography>
                          </React.Fragment>
                        }
                        secondary={
                          <Box>
                            <Typography
                              variant="body1"
                              style={{ marginBottom: "12px" }}
                            >
                              {getTruncated(lesson.lessonDescription, 150) +
                                "..."}
                            </Typography>
                            <Button
                              className={classes.startLesson}
                              edge="start"
                              variant="contained"
                              href={`/portal/ondemand/lessons/${lesson.lessonId}`}
                            >
                              Start Lesson
                            </Button>
                          </Box>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItem>

                    <Divider className={classes.divider} />
                  </div>
                </>
              ))}
          </List>

          <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 50, 100]}
            component="div"
            count={userLessons.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

SearchBox.js

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  TextField: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200,
  },
}));


export default function SearchBox(props) {

  const handlechangeSearch = (event) => {
    props.handleSearched(event.target.value);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextField
        id="outlined-search"
        label="Search"
        className={classes.TextField}
        onChange={handlechangeSearch}
        margin="dense"
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Need solution for the problem and I will be grateful to you. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I added 2 more functions 1 in parent component for keydown and 1 for on change with settimeout. Right now my api call is waiting for 2 sec. 

However, press enter key works but after 2 sec the api gets called again and it rerender it again with default result and flips back to entered result.

```

Comment: You need to debounce the api call. Loadash library has debounce utility that you can use or  the alternative would be that you write your own.  You can even write your own useDebounce hook. This video shows how to make an useDebounce hook and it is very insightful beacause it shows you some of the problems you might run into when debouncing an async api call: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXpLFRGM8kg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below make an API call when user stop typing or user press the enter key and not repeat the API call if the user press enter or stop typing, maybe it help

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')
  let delay;


const callApi = ()=> {
  console.log('call Api',searchText)

}


  useEffect(() => {
     delay = setTimeout(() => {
      if(searchText)callApi()
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearTimeout(delay)
  }, [searchText])

  const keyDown = (e)=>{
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      clearTimeout(delay)
      callApi()
      console.log('keyDown press and ready for api call')
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input
      value={searchText}
      type='text'
      placeholder='Search here...'
      onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={keyDown}
    />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Sir for your help, it works! I appreciate your help and effort and I wish I can get you a cup of coffee as a token of appreciation!

Comment: Nabil thanks it's a pleasure for me to know it helps

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 more functions 1 in parent component for keydown and 1 adjustment for searchedItem with settimeout inside parent. Right now my api call is waiting for 2 sec.

However, press enter key works fine but after 2 sec the api gets called again and it rerender the component with default values and flips back to entered result like in a flash.

Below are the func,

CourseList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemAvatar,
  ListItemText,
  Typography,
  Box,
  Divider,
  Grid,
  Button,
  TablePagination,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import LanguageDropdown from "./LanguageDropdown";
import RatingDropdown from "./RatingDropdown";
import CategoryDropdown from "./CategoryDropdown";
import LevelDropdown from "./LevelDropdown";
import StreamDropdown from "./StreamDropdown";

import SearchBox from "./SearchBox";
import CourseSort from "./CourseSort";

import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";


import settings from "../../../../settings";


const getTruncated = (items, value) => {
  // console.log("coming from getTruncated func ", items);

  let cut = items.indexOf(" ", value);
  if (cut == -1) {
    return items;
  }
  return items.substring(0, cut);
};


export default function CourseList(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [myCourses, setMyCourses] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [cate, setCate] = useState(true);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [userLessons, setUserLessons] = useState([]);
  const [delayDebounceFn, setDelayDebounceFn] = useState(0);

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    console.log("coming from useffect course list", window.location.pathname);

    if (window.location.pathname !== "/portal/ondemand") {
      setCate(false);
    }

    setMyCourses(props.userCourses);

    getInitSignon();

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [search]);

  const getInitSignon = () => {
    // initSignon
    const token = localStorage.getItem("cars-crm-token");

    console.log("coming after being search inside init", search);
    fetch(settings.api().lessons + `?SearchText=${search}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log("coming from course category", res);
          return res.json();
        } else {
          const error = new Error(res.error);
          throw error;
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("coming from onDemandcourse", data);
        setUserLessons(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  const searchedItem = (value) => {
    setTimeout(() => setSearch(value), 2000);
  };

  const keyDownSearched = (value) => {
    setSearch(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container className={classes.searchsort}>
        <Grid item>
          <SearchBox
            className={classes.searchContainer}
            handleSearched={searchedItem}
            keydownSearched={keyDownSearched}
          />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item>
          <CourseSort className={classes.sortContainer} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Grid className={classes.root}>
        <Grid item className={classes.filters}>
          <Grid direction="column">
            <LanguageDropdown courses={myCourses} />

            {cate && <CategoryDropdown />}

          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item>
          <List className={classes.courses}>
            {userLessons
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((lesson) => (
                <>
                  <div key={lesson.lessonId}>
                    <ListItem
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        alignItems: "flex-start",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        backgroundColor: "#fff",
                        padding: "16px 15px",
                      }}
                    >
                      <ListItemAvatar
                        component={Link}
                        to={`/portal/ondemand/lessons/${lesson.lessonId}`}
                      >
                        <Link
                          to={`/portal/ondemand/lessons/${lesson.lessonId}`}
                        >
                          <img
                            src={lesson.lessonThumbUrl}
                            className={classes.img}
                            alt={lesson.lessonTitle}
                          />
                        </Link>
                      </ListItemAvatar>

                      <ListItemText
                        style={{ margin: "0px" }}
                        primary={
                          <React.Fragment>
                            <Typography
                              component="span"
                              variant="body2"
                              className={classes.inline}
                              color="textPrimary"
                            >
                              <Box fontSize={20}>
                                <Typography
                                  className={classes.courseTitle}
                                  variant="h6"
                                >
                                  {lesson.lessonTitle}
                                </Typography>
                              </Box>
                              <Grid
                                container
                                direction="row"
                                justify="space-between"
                                style={{ margin: "12px 0", maxWidth: "50rem" }}
                              >
                                <Grid item>
                                  <Box fontStyle="italic">
                                    <Typography variant="h6">
                                      Code: {lesson.courseCode} &nbsp; | &nbsp;
                                      {lesson.lessonCreated
                                        ? lesson.lessonCreated.split("T")[0]
                                        : undefined}{" "}
                                      &nbsp; | &nbsp;Course:{" "}
                                      {lesson.courseTitle}
                                    </Typography>
                                  </Box>
                                </Grid>
                              </Grid>
                            </Typography>
                          </React.Fragment>
                        }
                        secondary={
                          <Box>
                            <Typography
                              variant="body1"
                              style={{ marginBottom: "12px" }}
                            >
                              {getTruncated(lesson.lessonDescription, 150) +
                                "..."}
                            </Typography>
                            <Button
                              className={classes.startLesson}
                              edge="start"
                              variant="contained"
                              href={`/portal/ondemand/lessons/${lesson.lessonId}`}
                            >
                              Start Lesson
                            </Button>
                          </Box>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItem>

                    <Divider className={classes.divider} />
                  </div>
                </>
              ))}
          </List>

          <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 50, 100]}
            component="div"
            count={userLessons.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

SearhcBox.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // container: {
  //     display: 'flex',
  //     flexWrap: 'wrap',
  //   },
  TextField: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200,
  },
}));

// go into CourseFilterBar
export default function SearchBox(props) {
  const keyDownSearched = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      props.keydownSearched(event.target.value);
    }

    console.log("coming from search box", event.target.value);
  };

  const handlechangeSearch = (event) => {
    props.handleSearched(event.target.value);
    console.log("coming from search box", event.target.value);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextField
        id="outlined-search"
        label="Search"
        className={classes.TextField}
        onChange={handlechangeSearch}
        onKeyDown={keyDownSearched}
        margin="dense"
        // fullWidth={true}
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [debouncing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) to achieve that. See [here](https://snack.expo.io/@l3m3a3/debounced-search) an example of how you can implement it. It is in React Native, but it is the same in React JS with the exception that you use TextField instead of TextInput and the props for events have other names.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { debounce } from 'debounce';

const makeRequest = term =>
  fetch(`https://postman-echo.com/get?term=${term}`).then(response =>
    response.json()
  );

export default function App() {
  // State for keeping the last response from API
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  // This makes the request immediately when called
  const getResponse = useCallback(term => {
    console.log('Make request with term: ', term);
    makeRequest(term).then(resp => setResponse(JSON.stringify(resp?.args)));
  }, []);

  // This schedules the getResponse function to be called after 2 seconds.
  // If in these 2 seconds debouncedGetResponse is called again, then it will
  // cancel the pending call and will schedule the new call to be run after
  // another 2 seconds.
  // We'll use this for onChangeText handler.
  const debouncedGetResponse = useCallback(debounce(getResponse, 2000), [
    getResponse,
  ]);

  // This will check for pending requests scheduled with debouncedGetResponse
  // and if there is a pending call it will be called immediately instead of
  // waiting those 2 seconds to finish.
  // We'll use this for onBlur handler.
  const debouncedGetResponseFlush = useCallback(
    () => debouncedGetResponse.flush(),
    [debouncedGetResponse]
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        onChangeText={debouncedGetResponse}
        onBlur={debouncedGetResponseFlush}
      />
      <Text>Response: {response}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderColor: '#cccccc',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
};
```

Comment: thank you Sir for your suggestion with debounced. I didn't try this tbh, because I already made changes with settimeout which was given by another genius like you. Anyways I appreciate your help and effort. I really appreciate that.